# Filter/Delete Emails in (Neo)Mutt without External Tools

Tags: email, unix, mutt

I want to delete emails based on rules in Mutt. I don't fetch the mails somewhere before I read them, I do everything directly on the IMAP server. How can I create preprocessor rules like: "If an email is from X, delete it."? I don't want to configure fetchmail/procmail and write new configs for accessing the email server all over again.

Answer (score 3):

For deleting emails by pattern use the operation *<delete-pattern>* (bound to the key "D" in the standard configuration). A pattern to select by sender is

> ~f sendername@sender.domain

To get a preview of the result you could also use this approach:

1. Tag the emails to delete by pattern using operation *<tag-pattern>* (key "T")
2. Delete the tagged emails using ops *<tag-prefix><delete-message>* (keys ";" "d")

Note: Patterns are described in the manual page of muttrc (command `man muttrc`) in the chapter *PATTERNS*.